# Why was /dev/null called that?

Tags: devices, history

I'm looking for some historic info about the null device. Why was it called `/dev/null` instead of (for example) `/dev/empty`?

[FreeBSD's manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?null(4)) states that "A null device appeared in Version 7 AT&T UNIX" but I can't find any reference or hint about why that name was originally chosen.

If it turns out that the name was originally used in a more ancient OS, I'd like to know how the original device worked and why *that* name was chosen.

Comment: `/dev/null` is one of very few pathnames standardized by POSIX. And [even non-Unix-like systems call it that way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) (probably because Unix did it first).

Comment: @Gilles ok but why? What the history behind this specific name?

Comment: I've removed everything except the core question itself from here in the hope that that makes it clearer as a historical question; if I've interfered with what you wanted it to say please roll it back.

Comment: The FreeBSD manual page is correct but somewhat misleading.  The null device, called `/dev/null`, was present in Version 6 Unix, in the mid 1970s.  (BTW, `/dev/zero` was added much later.) Unfortunately, I have no supporting evidence.

Comment: "on unix an "always blocking file" could be used to wait for signals." As it turns out, there's a system call that's used to wait for signals - `pause()`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick unix has tons of system calls that could be replaced with files.

Comment: [The FreeBSD man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?null(4)) says it appeared in AT&T UNIX version 4.

Answer (score 7):

`null` was chosen because [it discards any data sent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device), pretty much like a void place. That's why its also called black hole.

It is [a character device](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html), a stream that has no connection to a real space in memory. Fun fact is that [you can make your own personalized `/dev/null`](http://thelinuxstuff.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/how-do-you-create-devnull-device-and-use.html) with `mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3`.

Additionally, [it sends `EOF` if you try to read from it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html).

Answer (score 2):

'null' means 'nothing', 'without value', and so on.

'empty' implies a container. For emptiness to exist we need a container.

In computer science in which zero is a value, we need a term for 'nothing'. So  we have the 'null pointer' for example which is, functionally, a pointer to nothing.

'/dev/null' is the 'nothing device'. If we want something to disappear into nothingness, we give it to the nothing device.

If we give something to /dev/empty then the 'empty' device is no longer empty  but is the container of the thing we sent to it.